# Как запустить приложение с помощью клавиши громкости?

Tags: java, android

Суть заключается в том что бы при двойном нажатии на клавишу громкости запускалось приложение. Подскажите пожалуйста это делается в настройках телефона или при создании приложения? Приложение делаю на java.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 1):

Не очень понятно какое именно приложение - ваше или чье-то. Вот как в вашей программе можно обработать нажатия на кнопку громкости:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN)){
        *****
    }
    return true;
}
```

[вот тут описано](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7297242/any-way-to-detect-volume-key-presses-or-volume-changes-with-android-service) как отслеживать нажатия через фоновый процесс

Comment: В общем суть приложения которое я хочу создать: При двойном нажатии на кнопку громкости приложение запускалось. В приложении два поля для ввода текста. Первое это название второе описание. После того как человек заполняет эти два поля и повторно делает двойное нажатие на кнопку громкости текст поля описания сохранялся с названием первого поля и возвращался в предыдущее состояние которое было до запуска.